# Tablet for using as a digital frame

Tags: tablet, displays

I was willing to buy a digital frame for my photos but, after some research and seeing the prices, I'm starting to think that a tablet under 100 USD should perform much better than the digital frames available (i.e, I've read many people complaining about the software, the quality of display, the resolution, the inconvenience of not having a USB port).

My intention is to spend between 50 and 100 USD for a device that has HD display and that can be easily put into shuffle mode for pictures or put to sleep at night. It would be awesome if it had a SD/USB slot. Ideally, it wouldn't mess with the resolution commonly used with smartphones/digital cameras. My guess is that Android devices would be more complete/versatile than closed, end product, digital portraits, am I correct?